# Is there a way to double click on chrome selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a test script. My test is failing at a certain point as the button needs to be clicked twice.

I've temporarily changed my code so it includes the same piece of code twice and that does the trick. But is there a way of introducing a double click instead?

**Code :**

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
```

This is full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class RunPath
    {

            static void Main()
            {

                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            String title = webDriver.Title;
            String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";
            if (title.Contains(expectedTitle))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tile is matching with expected value");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tile is matching with expected value");
            }
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@type = 'text']")).SendKeys("W30PN#");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@type = 'text']")).Clear();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@type = 'text']")).SendKeys("W30PN");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
```

Comment: when I am doing it manually , I have clicked only once and it worked.

Comment: Yes, so the first two times it does it once. But when it gets to the third it bizarrely doesn't accept one click

Answer (score 1):

You may Refer this,

**Using Action Class:**

```
    Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
    action.MoveToElement("Web Element To Click").DoubleClick().Perform();
```

**Using JavaScriptExecutor:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dblclick();", "Element to Click");
```

Comment: I introduced your code but it doesn't seem to do the double click. When i have the same piece of code written twice like above it works fine

Comment: What you mean by "it doesn't seem to do Double click"?  Are you getting an exception, Please share more details.?

Comment: @L.Dockster You may refer updated Syntax reference to c#

Comment: I've pasted the remainder of my code above. I don't get an exception but once i enter my string of data my last bit of code goes and clicks a 'continue' button. This button needs to be clicked twice so it goes onto the next page. With your code it doesn't go onto the next page as i believe it isn't doing the double click

Comment: @L.Dockster These are the only possible method to have double click. Refer another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. All you need to do is **scroll down** to the specific element (in your case it is **continue** button) instead of `double click`.

Code you can try out :

```
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
IWebElement postcode =  
webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[placeholder='Postcode']"));
postcode.Clear();
postcode.SendKeys("B33 8TH");
IWebElement email =  webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[placeholder='Email (Optional)']"));
email.Clear();
email.SendKeys("L.dockster@stackoverflow.com");
((IJavascriptExecutor) webDriver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 700)");
webDriver.findElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Continue']")).Click();
```

Comment: I've tried the continue button same result. What i'm doing is going to the URL clicking continue button getting a error, putting in an incorrect post code getting an error then putting in a correct post code and continuing on

Comment: from my end code is working fine. Now , in your case you can navigate to URL and after that you will have to scroll down to click on continue button  ,because continue button is not visible to us and obviously to browser too , so you might get this exception : `other element received the click (x,y)`